# CMAKE Forcing copy of specified files in post build even if no change in source files

Tags: cmake

I have a project laid out like so:

```
CMakeLists.txt
|
|--------subdir1
|          |--CMakeLists.txt
|          |--sourcefiles
|          |--filetocopy1
|
|--------subdir2
           |--CMakeLists.txt
           |--sourcefiles
           |--filetocopy2
```

I want to copy filetocopy1 and filetocopy2 to a specified output directory in the build folder. So in both, I have something like

```
add_custom_command(                                                                                                                                                       
  TARGET nameoftargetinsubdir1                                                                                                                                             
  POST_BUILD                                                                                                                                                              
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy                                                                                                                                        
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filetocopy1"                                                                                                    
  "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"                                                                                                                                     
  )
```

The problem is that if the filetocopy1 or filetocopy2 change, but the source files don't, then invoking make in the build folder doesn't copy the files. Is there some way to force it to copy those files? I'm getting the feeling I might have to put the copy commands in the top level CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Did you try to add `filetocopy1` to your list of source files of target `nameoftargetinsubdir1` to trigger copies on changes of the file? And - if we are talking about VS environments - did you know about the [`VS_COPY_TO_OUT_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/VS_COPY_TO_OUT_DIR.html) source file property?

Comment: filecopy1 isn't in my list of source files. I assumed I was only supposed to put c or cpp files in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you simply want to copy these files to another place, I recommend to use the following command:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filetocopy1 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ COPYONLY)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/configure_file.html

This command is simple and effective. And it will copy your file to the destination, whenever cmake is invoked.

Comment: Just a hint: If you really want to copy the file each time CMake (re-)configures you should remove the `COPYONLY` option. Otherwise CMake generated make/build environments would be satisfied if the source file is not newer then the output file.

Comment: Ok this seems to do what I wanted! Great! One comment: My destination for the copy is ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin which is also where all the library files go. If I do not create this folder in the top CMakeLists.txt, then at configure, the "configure_file" command creates a file called "bin" and copies "filetocopy1" to that. Which then causes make to fail. So I have to explicitly create the "bin" folder in the top level cmake to avoid this. Just thought it was strange. With the command I had before, I did not have to do that.

Comment: While configure_file is a concise solution, it's not a post build step.

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of *POST_BUILD* custom commands is being run whenever target executable/library is rebuilt. If you don't need such behavior, use common custom commands with *OUTPUT* and *DEPENDS* option, combined with `add_custom_target`:

```
# If someone needs file "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/filetocopy1",
# this command will create it if the file doesn't exist or is older than
# "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filetocopy1".
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/filetocopy1"
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filetocopy1"
  "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"
  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/filetocopy1"
  )

# Custom target for activate the custom command above
add_custom_target(copy_file1 DEPENDS "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/filetocopy1")

# Whenever target 'nameoftargetinsubdir1' is requested, the custom target will be evaluated.
add_dependencies(nameoftargetinsubdir1 copy_file1)
```